# Manipulate $\cos(x)$ to return $1$ if median value in a fixed range is provided

Tags: calculus

I know nothing about maths, so please forgive my poor explanation and the title of the question.

I need a function f(x) that given a range consisting of a lower bound (b1) and a upper bound (b2), returns 1 if x is exactly (b1+b2)/2 and that tends to 0 (returning exactly 0) if x tends to the bounds. The function should produce any value between [0,1] given values between [b1,b2].

I tried playing with cos(x) with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Even if the answer is simple, why not make it an answer instead of a comment? That way the question will not hang around as "unanswered".

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Normally I would agree.  However, here, you have to worry about the *answer* *police*.  Has the OP shown work or given problem background or his background?  The only way to clear the path to allowing an answer here, without worry, is to change the mathSE protocol.

Comment: @user2661923 Oh yes, there is that.

Comment: It's easier to play with $\sin$ instead of $\cos$ in my opinion. Consider the general function $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{L}\right)$ and note that $\sin(0)=\sin(\pi)=0$. Now determine $a$ and $L$ from these boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea with $\cos(x)$, since we have $\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ and $\cos(0)=1,$ so it already satisfies the properties of your function with $b_1=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $b_2=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

How do you obtain the correct function for any $b_1$ and $b_2$?

You will have to stretch and translate your function, so consider $f(x)=\cos(ax+b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants to be determined. Since $f(b_1)=f(b_2)=0$ we have the system

$$\cos(ab_1+b)=\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\implies ab_1+b=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\cos(ab_2+b)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\implies ab_2+b=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Note the solution will not be unique and you can also consider $\sin(x)$ as mentioned by projectilemotion in the comments.